# Get parent variable in child controller

Tags: php, cakephp, http-redirect

I have `Lessons` that belong to `Courses`. I want an added lesson to redirect to that lesson's course index instead of the overall Lessons index.

I have tried this in my `add()` function:

```
return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'courses', 'action' => 'view', $this->Lesson->Course->$id));
```

But the redirect is not working. How do I make it so that it goes back to 
http://www.example.com/courses/view/2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$this->Lesson->Course->$id will not give you the course id out of box.

I suppose the course id is already in the request, $this->request->data['Lesson']['course_id'];